# Four archetypal figures in Stephenson's "Diamond Age" and in Rajaniemi's "Le Flambeur trilogy"

Tags: neal-stephenson, jean-le-flambeur, archetypes

Warning: minor spoilers to "Diamond Age" and "Le Flambeur" ahead.

In "Le Flambeur", there are four Aun: Chimney Princess, Green Soldier, Kraken of Light and Flower Prince, former imaginary friends of Matjek Chen, now living memes, representing (as Rajaniemi puts it himself) "The Goddess. The Mentor. The Shapeshifter. The Trickster".

In "Diamond Age", one of the main heroes, Nell, is educated (through an interactive Primer) by four characters, modeled after her childhood toys: Duck, Dinosaur, Purple and Peter Rabbit. From the book it is quite clear that they represent the same archetypal figures.

I wonder, did both authors base this on some religious studies, or were Rajaniemi's Aun somehow an homage to Stephenson?

Comment: These are likely both based on archetypes from Joseph Campbell's studies of myth - Campbell leans heavily on the idea of archetypal figures repeating in similar forms throughout stories from diverse cultures. Campbell's got more than four key archetypes that he describes, but it may just be a coincidence if two authors chose the same subset of four.

Comment: Maybe this would be better answered if it were moved to Literature StackExchange ?